# VBA CountA Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting Error 1004.  I'm not sure how else to declare my object in order to avoid this error:

```
Sub DeleteBlank()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate

    'Delete Blank Columns
    For col = 1 To 4
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(i)) = 0 Then
            ws.Columns.Delete
        End If
    Next col


End Sub
```

Comment: Your `For` loop is iterating through the values of `col`, but then you use `i` within it.

Comment: You can avoid errors like this in the future by using `Option Explicit` because it'll whine at you when you try to use an undeclared variable

Comment: That's embarrassing, thank you!

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, Thank you! I absolutely will.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 well technically `Option Explicit` wouldn't whine if OP had declared both `col` and `i` - nevertheless, a good recommendation.

Comment: @BigBen good point, good point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step backwards and use col not i. Also, can wrap in a With.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteBlank()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim col As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For col = 4 To 1 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(col)) = 0 Then
                .Columns(col).Delete
            End If
        Next col
    End With
End Sub
```